# How do I use js variables in html?

Tags: javascript, html, var

This is where I'm at.

**JavaScript:**

```
var name = 'Bob Test';
document.getElementById('Bob Test').innerHTML = name;
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="name"></p>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = 'Bob Test';
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
```

You were using `'Bob Test'` as the id in `getElementById()` when you should be using the id of the element you want to add to. In this case it is `'name'`

Comment: and I would link my js file to my html with


    <script src="myJS.js"></script>

Comment: It depends on where your JS file is located, but yes you are correct, if the JS file is at the same level as the html file this will work.

Comment: Once linked, should I be able to use:         <p id="name"></p> and it will work?

Comment: And if I can't get it to display anything?

Comment: Check your browser console to see if you have any errors in there.  Its possible that you are not linking your JS file correctly too.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="myJS.js"></script>

Comment: I cannot say whether or not that is correct because I do not know your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
document.getElementById('Bob Test').innerHTML = name;
```

use

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;
```

because your id is 'name'

Comment: So I would then be able to use those variables in html?

Comment: You can use <script> _here type your js code_ </script> inside your html.

Answer (score 0):

Class use as much as possible

```
<p class="name"></p>
```

my suggestion

```
var name = 'Bob Test';
document.getElementByClassName('name').innerHTML=name;
```

Because class can modify multiple element where.
 Id only selecting first element.
 You can use Queryselector.

For use of CSS selector.
If you aware it just like

Jquery Selector.

And your current solution is

```
document.getElementId('name').innerHTML = name;
```